# redirection in a required page in php

Tags: php, header

I have two scripts `get.php` and `auth.php` where i 've required `auth.php` in `get.php`, so here's the deal the redirection statement in `auth.php` i.e, `header()` is **not working** for some reason, any quick thoughts on this problem if this can be achieved or not??

Comment: please include some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, your problem is that:

```
header("location:[XYX.PHP]") is not working.
```

It generally does not work due to some output is print already on the page.
Please use

> ob_start();

at very the beginning of the page.
This starts output buffering.
And the redirection works.

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location: $URL")` may not work if you already sent headers by some `echo`, `print_r` or similar function.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your web server error logs, does it mention something like "headers already sent" ? If yes that means you're probably outputting something *before* your `header()` function call

Answer (score 0):

**get.php**

```
<?php include_once("auth.php"); ?>
```

**auth.php**

Redirect using the code below which is based on the example found at  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.stackoverflow.com/"); ?>
```

If it still doesn't work, make sure (like it says on http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) that you are not outputting any html or even blank spaces or before calling the header() function. (Perhaps your get.php page is outputting empty space or HTML tags before including auth.php.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function for this task

echo "window.open(url1, "name1", params);";